# Error running WSGI application , ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I am trying to deploy my Django project through the project using pythonanywhere but I am getting a problem and am really stuck. Can anyone help me with that. The image attached to the path to my setting.py file. [Path to settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfyXp.png)  .

The WSGI.py configuration on Webttab is:

```
path = '/home/technewsandblog/blog/blog_project/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

# then:

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And The Error shows after I reload is:

```
Error running WSGI application
2018-07-08 20:30:23,383: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'

2018-07-08 20:30:23,383:   File "/var/www/technewsandblog_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>

2018-07-08 20:30:23,383:     application = get_wsgi_application()

2018-07-08 20:30:23,384: 
2018-07-08 20:30:23,384:   File "/home/technewsandblog/.virtualenvs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application

2018-07-08 20:30:23,384:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)

2018-07-08 20:30:23,384: 
2018-07-08 20:30:23,384:   File "/home/technewsandblog/.virtualenvs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup

2018-07-08 20:30:23,384:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)

2018-07-08 20:30:23,384: 
2018-07-08 20:30:23,385:   File "/home/technewsandblog/.virtualenvs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
2018-07-08 20:30:23,385:     self._setup(name)

2018-07-08 20:30:23,385: 
2018-07-08 20:30:23,385:   File "/home/technewsandblog/.virtualenvs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup

2018-07-08 20:30:23,385:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

2018-07-08 20:30:23,385: 

2018-07-08 20:30:23,386:   File "/home/technewsandblog/.virtualenvs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__

2018-07-08 20:30:23,386:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your path needs to be `/home/technewsandblog/blog/blog_project`.

Currently, your path of `/home/technewsandblog/blog/blog_project/mysite` and settings module `mysite.settings` means that it is expecting a settings.py file at `/home/technewsandblog/blog/blog_project/mysite/mysite/settings.py`

Also check out the PythonAnywhere help page on [WSGI import errors](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/). (in particular the Django section)

Comment: Than you so much, I got it running now #pythonanywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Flask and encountering this, it might be a Python version mismatch.
Install any package (even if it's already installed), You'll find the path where your packages are getting installed, Check the path to see if you'll find the Python version there, If you do, then just delete your app from the web tab and reinstall it using that Python version.
nb: (Only the web section will be deleted, your code will remain intact.)