# pythonanywhere wsgi module not found error

Tags: pythonanywhere

I´m trying to host a django web site on the pythonanywhere hosting service, but I´m getting the following error message:

```
2018-10-21 20:56:14,359: Error running WSGI application
2018-10-21 20:56:14,365: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'energiasc'
2018-10-21 20:56:14,365:   File "/var/www/adrielw_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 24, in <module>
2018-10-21 20:56:14,365:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2018-10-21 20:56:14,365: 
2018-10-21 20:56:14,365:   File "/home/adrielw/.virtualenvs/my_env_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2018-10-21 20:56:14,366:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2018-10-21 20:56:14,366: 
2018-10-21 20:56:14,366:   File "/home/adrielw/.virtualenvs/my_env_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2018-10-21 20:56:14,366:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2018-10-21 20:56:14,366: 
2018-10-21 20:56:14,366:   File "/home/adrielw/.virtualenvs/my_env_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
2018-10-21 20:56:14,366:     self._setup(name)
2018-10-21 20:56:14,367: 
2018-10-21 20:56:14,367:   File "/home/adrielw/.virtualenvs/my_env_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
2018-10-21 20:56:14,367:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2018-10-21 20:56:14,367: 
2018-10-21 20:56:14,367:   File "/home/adrielw/.virtualenvs/my_env_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
2018-10-21 20:56:14,368:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2018-10-21 20:56:14,368: ***************************************************
2018-10-21 20:56:14,368: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2018-10-21 20:56:14,368: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2018-10-21 20:56:14,368: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
```

---

My settings.py file goes like this>>>

```
import os
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/adrielw/energsc/energiasc'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, project_home)



# set environment variable to tell django where your settings.py is
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'energiasc.settings'


# serve django via WSGI
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

my files structure is like this >>>

[first level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G0Yg.png)

[next level of file directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUOxp.png)

I´m bewildered!! Any ideas?

But the way there was a similar problem in this post, but that doesnt helped me([Error running WSGI application , ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235954/error-running-wsgi-application-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysite/52919821#52919821))!!

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
project_home = '/home/adrielw/energsc'
```

With your current code it is trying to find a settings file at

```
/home/adrielw/energsc/energiasc/energiasc/settings.py
```

Comment: still not working... I gave up... for the moment of trying... if later I have time I come back to this... thanks thought !!! @conrad