# Error running WSGI application, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'. Also not able to find Static files

Tags: django, static, settings, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my website using pythonanywhere. I've given the correct path in wsgi file which is as follows (see code below). Still I'm getting a ModuleNotFoundError.
Also, it's not able to find Static files, however, they are at correct location.

Wsgi file code:

```
{ 
    path = '/home/divyanshu964/portfolio/Personal_portfolio/'
    
    if path not in sys.path:
            sys.path.insert(0, path)
 
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Personal_portfolio.settings'

    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    application = get_wsgi_application()
}
```

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Show us full traceback error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error running WSGI application , ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235954/error-running-wsgi-application-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysite)

Comment: I've already given the correct path, so that shouldn't be the issue , so no it doesn't help

Comment: looks like you need to reload your web app on the "web" page on PythonAnywhere

Comment: I already reloaded several times. Nothing happens

Comment: It looks like you are looking at the top of the error log, not at the bottom. What is the most recent error? `No module named 'mysite'` does not match your WSGI config.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @DivyanshuRaghuwanshi to load static files  you can set `DEBUG=True` inside **settings.py**  but it's not a good practice to set **DEBUG** on in production so another way is to set your `DEBUG=False` and create **STATIC_ROOT** and configure it inside project root **urls.py** and than run `python manage.py collectstatic` command and than give path of your static root directory in pythonanywhere configuration

Answer (score 0):

Apart from settings directly related to Django, there are some extra steps on PythonAnywhere.

- wsgi file: you need to edit the file that is linked on the Web app page, not a file inside your project (check the docs [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/))
- static files: set up static files mappings on the Web app page as well (check the docs [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/)).